# Como solucionar android.databinding.tool.processing.ScopedException: [databinding] {"msg":"[44 68 44 68 44 68 25] must include a layout"

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, avd

Compañeros, al momento de la implementacion de un recyclerView, mediante la etiqueta `include` en el `activity_main.xml` me produce el siguiente error.

`android.databinding.tool.processing.ScopedException: [databinding] {"msg":"[44 68 44 68 44 68 25] must include a layout","file":"C:\\Users\\User\\L2_ScriptsPro\\6_Project_Android_Apps\\F01_FirebaseApp\\app\\src\\main\\res\\layout\\activity_main.xml","pos":[]}`

[image: ScopedException]

Estuve investigando un poco su causa, mencionan algo de una etiqueta `data`, pero sigo sin lograr encontrar alguna solucion o respuesta un poco mas clara al momento de presentar los layouts en el emulador.

Codigo: `activity_main.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/id_txtView_TextMsgActMain"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Initial Msg"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:gravity="end"
            android:paddingStart="5dp"
            android:paddingEnd="20dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="15dp"
            />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/id_btn_ShowMsgActMain"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Show Msg Fire"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            />


    </LinearLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/id_fram_recListView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            >

            <include
                android:layout="@layout/stock_items_list"
                />

        </LinearLayout>
    </FrameLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Codigo `stock_items_list.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/id_recy_stockItems"
    app:layoutManager="LinearLayoutManager"
    />
```

Agradezco de antemano su cordial ayuda y conocimiento acerca de lo que puedo estar causando, aunque supongo que es en parte al `viewBinding` que lo esta generando, y lo que deberia hacer para solventarlo.

Saludos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En tu include, esto es incorrecto:

```
 <include
   android:layout="@layout/stock_items_list"
  />
```

debes cargar el layout de esta forma usando el atributo `layout` :

```
<include
  layout="@layout/stock_items_list"
 />
```